# Appending a new line character to a variable in a for loop Windows batch

Tags: batch-file, append, newline, windows-scripting

I am looping through the results of a command and appending them all to one variable (`!results!`) within that loop. At the end of the loop, if the results are not empty then I print them. I would like each result to appear on a new line.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set results=
set lf=^

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('call mvn dependency:analyze ^| findstr "WARNING"')
    do ( set results=!results!!lf!%%a )
    if not [!results!]==[] (
        echo. ------------------------------------
        echo. FOUND MATCHES 
        echo. ------------------------------------
        echo. !results! 
        echo. ------------------------------------
        echo. ------------------------------------
        echo. && echo.
    )
```

I'm trying to use a new line batch hack that I've seen on here, but it doesn't seem to be working in this context.

**What I'm getting**

```
------------------------------------
FOUND MATCHES 
------------------------------------
[WARNING] Used undeclared dependencies found: [WARNING]    org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile   [WARNING]    org
    .springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile         [WARNING]    xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.04:compile
------------------------------------
------------------------------------
```

**What I'd like**

```
------------------------------------
FOUND MATCHES 
------------------------------------
[WARNING] Used undeclared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile   
[WARNING]    org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile         
[WARNING]    xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.04:compile
------------------------------------
------------------------------------
```

Comment: Could you give a short example of what you are getting vs what you want?

Comment: Sure, added an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get it running at all, I had to add some `setlocal` statements and add extra blank line between `set lf=^` and the `for`. Once I did that, I actually see different output than you:

```
 !results!!lf!%a
[WARNING] a
[WARNING] c
```

This can easily be fix to work on my (Win7) machine by simply adding the following before the `for`:

```
set results=
```

There will be a leading blank line in the output, but it surely be surprised by adding a conditional when data is added to `results`.

But given the difference in the output you get, I guess we'll need to take a different approach to get it working for you. This should be much more robust than playing with newlines anyway.

```
@echo off
setlocal
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set showed_header=0
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('call mvn dependency:analyze ^| findstr "WARNING"') do (
   if !showed_header!==0 (
      set showed_header=1
      echo ------------------------------------
      echo FOUND MATCHES 
      echo ------------------------------------
   )

   echo %%a
)

if %showed_header%==1 (
   echo ------------------------------------
   echo ------------------------------------
   echo.
   echo.
)
```

Tested using `perl -e"print qq{[WARNING] a\nb\n[WARNING] c\n}"`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm interested that you got the original version to work. Sorry, I forgot to copy the `set results=` from my code. Even with the `setlocal` commands and two blank lines below `set lf=^` it doesn't seem to be working...

Comment: The `for` loop wasn't working for me at all since the `set lf=^` was eating it. I didn't know about `^`, so I was really confused. Adding a second blank line worked. Maybe MS fixed a problem? I'm using Win7.

Comment: Interesting, as I am on Win7 as well but it didn't seem to work. You're alternatively solution works very nicely though, so I think I'll stick to that, thanks!